# How to send a list to '...' in function to send multiple arguments for %like%

Tags: r

I am working on developing a function. The objective has yet been achieved, but I am aiming to grab names from a column in preparation for linear modelling. This step is not necessary for the question.

Essentially, I want to pass a list to the `...` in the function, i.e.

```
require(data.table)
require(tidyverse)
require(faraway)

another_fun <- function(...){
  #set the arguments
  pr <- list(...)
  return(pr[[1]])
}
another_fun(c('gamble', 'data'), 'data')
```

The reason is so that I can run the following function:

```
another_function <- function(data,...){
  #set the arguments
  pr <- list(...)
  response=pr[[1]]
  nm <- names(data)
  #get the predictors
  nm<-nm[!nm %in% response]
  
  nm_data<-sapply(1:length(nm), function(i) c(nm[-(0:i)], nm[0:i])) %>% data.frame()
  comb_predictors <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(nm_data)){
  
  comb_predictors[[i]] <- nm_data[1:i,]
  }
  predictors_wanted<- comb_predictors %>% 
    seq_along() %>% 
    data.frame(row=., boolean=sapply(comb_predictors, rowwise) %like% pr[[2]]) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = boolean) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    data.frame() %>% 
    split.data.frame(seq(nrow(.)))

   predictors <- Map(function(a, b)a[unlist(b)], dt, predictors_wanted)
  
return(predictors)
}
```

Then call the function for example:

```
another_function(data=teengamb, response='gamble',predictor=c('sex','status')
```

However, I get a big error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(a, unlist(b)) : undefined columns selected
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In grepl(pattern, vector, ignore.case = ignore.case, fixed = fixed) :
> argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> Error in `[.data.frame`(a, unlist(b)) : undefined columns selected

I believe the error is here:

```
data.frame(row=., boolean=sapply(dt, rowwise) %like% pr[[2]])
```

`%like%` does not like taking more than one predictor.

The above works perfectly fine when I run with:

```
another_function(data=teengamb, response='gamble',predictor='sex')
```

Expected output:

```
[[1]]
      X1  X4
1 status  sex

[[2]]
      X1  X4
1 status  sex
2 income status

[[3]]
      X1    X3         X4
1 status  verbal      sex
2 income   sex       status
3 verbal   status    income

[[4]]
      X1     X2     X3     X4
1 status income verbal    sex
2 income verbal    sex status
3 verbal    sex status income
4    sex status income verbal
```

Comment: You may use `grepl(paste(pr[[2]], collapse = "|"), ..`.  In addition, your function is showing error with `another_function(data=teengamb, response='gamble',predictor='sex')`

Comment: There is an object `dt` inside the function that was not defined

Comment: @akrun yeah that's the error I now get when I use your mentioned code. Any idea what is missing? It works fine when I just use `pr[[2]]`, and a single predictor

Comment: Your post says `another_function(data=teengamb, response='gamble',predictor='sex')` is working fine and getting the desired output which I didn't get.  Maybe you had `dt` defined in the global env

Comment: @akrun I misunderstood, the `x` is missing because we must place the `.` inside `grepl`. But then I get this error: ```Error in UseMethod("rowwise") : 
no applicable method for 'rowwise' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"```. Let me update the post maybe I made an edit that stops it working.

Comment: can you update your function so that it works for testing with single input

Comment: That line would be a wrong sytax i.e. `sapply(teengamb, rowwise)#
Error in UseMethod("rowwise")` :   Maybe you want `teengamb %>% rowwise`

Comment: @akrun it should work now - I made a silly mistake, I was transferring between two code edits so I ended up placing `dt` in there instead of `comb_predictors` for the main dataframe. I have fixed this. On the additional note, I have used the `grepl` as you mentioned with two predictors, it does not match `sex` nor `status` as I get `FALSE` for all cells

Comment: @akrun it works! all we needed was the paste function. This would make sense as we would be selecting `either, or`.

Comment: Thanks, in the expected output for `[[3]]`, why is 'X2' not selected i.e. it shows 'income', 'verbal', 'sex' where 'sex' is one of the entries

Comment: Bad idea to use either `dt` or `df` as local object names. It invites confusing error messages since both are names of base R functions.

Comment: Instead of using the pivot_longer etc.  why not just add `lapply(comb_predictors, function(dat) Filter(function(x) any(pr[[2]] %in% x), dat))` after creating the `comb_predictors`

Comment: @akrun your alternative is definitely much cleaner! it saves me tons of code, if I understand it correctly: we filter for any of the strings passed to `pr[[2]]` in each list? it's so brilliantly simple!

Comment: @IRTFM I agree, I had some scrap code that I use alongside my main script and I somehow passed this onto here. I do not usually give variables names like that but when I am developing quick code I usually give short and random names.